# Why do class properties not work if there is no subclass object?

Tags: python, class, subclass

I noticed that if you have a `property` in your class with a `setter` function, it won't work unless you subclass something. Here's an example:

This does not print anything to the output, and does not set the value

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self):
        self.tax = 3

    @property
    def cost(self):
        self._cost = 15
        return self._cost - self.tax

    @cost.setter
    def cost(self, value):
        self._cost = value
        print "New Cost: {}".format(self._cost - self.tax)

mycls = MyClass()
mycls.cost = 55
```

But if I subclass `object`, it works fine:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.tax = 3

    @property
    def cost(self):
        self._cost = 15
        return self._cost - self.tax

    @cost.setter
    def cost(self, value):
        self._cost = value
        print "New Cost: {}".format(self._cost - self.tax)

mycls = MyClass()
mycls.cost = 55
```

```
>>> New Cost: 52
```

Why exactly is this? And what is `object`?

Comment: These two pieces of code look exactly the same... Copy & paste mistake?

Comment: Did you mean to subclass `object` in your first code snippet?

Comment: This is only in Python2, in Python 3, all classes are inherited from Object automatically.

Comment: Does this question and its answers help you understand what's going on here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54867/what-is-the-difference-between-old-style-and-new-style-classes-in-python

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html

Comment: If you are using Python 2, you really shouldn't be unless you have a very good reason... (like maintaining an old code base).

Comment: Sorry about that! Edited code. Thanks for sharing the links, that helps explain it better :)